# Filtering with P6SPY

Tags: filtering, p6spy

Is there a way to set the filter in p6spy, such that it only logs "insert/delete/update" and NOT "select" SQL statements?

Documentation of p6spy mentions:
"P6Spy allows you to monitor specific tables or specific statement types"

An example they gave was the following:

> An example showing capture of all
>   select statements, except the orders
>   table follows:
>
> ```
> filter = true
> # comma separated list of tables to include
> include = select
> # comma separated list of tables to exclude
> exclude = orders
> ```

So I thought, there must be a way to include insert, delete, updates and exclude select... hence, I prepared my properties file like so:

```
filter = true
# comma separated list of tables to include
include = insert,update,delete
# comma separated list of tables to exclude
exclude = select
```

but that does not seem to work. Anyone with any suggestions??

Answer (score 1):

The key to the answer is in the comments

```
# comma separated list of tables to include
include = select
```

`select` is a name of a table, not the type of a statement.
It seems impossible to filter by statement types (at least by `select`/`update`/`delete`) easily. You'll be able to do it by using

```
# sql expression to evaluate if using regex filtering
sqlexpression=

#allows you to use a regex engine or your own matching engine to determine
#which statements to log
stringmatcher=com.p6spy.engine.common.GnuRegexMatcher
```

Answer (score 0):

The [definition](https://p6spy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configandusage.html#filter-include-exclude) has changed. In short, you can use what the OP used i.e:

```
filter=true
# comma separated list of *******STRINGS******* to include
include=insert,update,delete
# comma separated list of *******STRINGS******* to exclude
exclude=select
```

Or if you want to have more control, you can use [sqlexpression](https://p6spy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configandusage.html#filter-sqlexpression) like so:

```
filter=true
sqlexpression=^(.*(from\\scustomers).*)$
```